# The URL added while adding featured image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working with wordpress latest version.
As in wordrpess, we can add URL while adding a featured image in a post as there are text fields like caption, title, alt text, description, URL etc.
I've added a link like [http://example.com/abc-news](http://example.com/abc-logo)
I am fine to show the featured image in the blog post but I want that link as

```
<a href="URL" title="">{featured-image}</a>
```

So that, if anyone clicks on the featured image he/she will go to that link.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the default theme with the latest version of WordPress, you can edit **content.php** in the 2014 theme directory.

You need to wrap `<?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>` with the link code pointing to your URL.

This code should be around line 13 in content.php.

```
<?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

To link to the current blog post, you could add this code:

```
<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '"><?php twentyfourteen_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
```

If you are using a different theme than the default, open the file which contains The Loop in your theme, search for `the_post_thumbnail` or a similarly named function, and change the code as above.

The exact answer will vary depending on theme, but 98% of the time the fix should be similar to the above. Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Here's some more information: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Post_Thumbnail_Linking_to_the_Post_Permalink

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your prompt reply.
You are right that it's 98% depending on the theme.
The theme is using a `meta_value` to add a custom URL for the featured image.
So, I need to get that URL through `get_post_meta`
[I've got from here.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)
And I am fine with it now. :-)

Thanks